# OS X cmake linking stdlibc++, mongodb c++ driver issue

Tags: c++, macos, mongodb, cmake, clang

I want to use MongoDB C++ driver in my project. I've downloaded sources and built this driver following accompanied recommendations. When I'm building my project, using this driver I receive huge bunch of linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "mongo::causedBy(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
                   std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
        mongo::DBException::addContext(std::__1::basic_string<char,
                                       std::__1::char_traits<char>,
                                       std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
                                                              in main.cpp.o
  "mongo::UserException::appendPrefix(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char,
                                      std::__1::char_traits<char>,
                                      std::__1::allocator<char> >&) const",
                                                         referenced from:
      vtable for mongo::ConnectException in main.cpp.o
  "std::string::copy(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      mongo::(anonymous namespace)::SSLManager::password_cb(char*, int, int, void*)
                                               in libmongoclient.a(ssl_manager.o)
  "std::string::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const",
                                                                 referenced from:
  ........
```

It seems like there is some issue with linking c++ standart library. Without mongoDB driver related code everything building fine. What can be a reason of such issue and how can it be solved? I'm using cmake, OS is OS X 10.9.2.

**UPD**
also linker command is:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld"
-demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -o steven
-search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/steven.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a 
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a 
/usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.a 
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -lc++ -lSystem
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Comment: What version of the driver are you trying to compile?

Comment: @daveh I got actual legacy branch version from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver. In fact I managed to compile driver itself. I've got issue when trying to use driver's library it in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this issue. The reason was using different version of stdlib while compiling driver and the whole application with driver library linked. I changed driver library scorn build command to:

```
scons --prefix=/usr/local --ssl install-mongoclient
      --64 --c++11 --libc++ --osx-version-min=10.7
```

instead of:

```
scons --prefix=/usr/local --ssl install-mongoclient --64
```

and now linker produce no error and simple tutorial application even connects mongo if mongod is running

another useful information could be CMakeLists.txt for those my project using mongo db c++ driver:

```
project(proj_name)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -v")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread filesystem system program_options REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(proj_name ${Boost_LIBRARIES} /usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a)
```